# does implicit typecasting takes place in java, when super class reference is pointing to sub class object?

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

when super class reference is pointing to sub class object,during execution does jvm type cast obejct from sub to super type and store it in reference variable?

```
class Animal {

void bark() {
    System.out.println("Animal is barking");
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal{

void bark() {
    System.out.println("Dog is barking");
  }
}

public class DynamicBinding {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Animal a = new Dog();  //does implicit type casting happens at this line?
    a.bark();
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't believe so, no.  At least most of the time, the compiler will statically analyze your code and determine that no casts are needed.  If one is needed, it will insist you manually add it.  I don't believe therefore that a JVM is constantly checking objects at runtime to make certain their types are correct.

Comment: You don't need to cast a type to its supertype. `new B()` *is* a `A` by definition.

Comment: Dog extends A or Animal class and `A a = new B();` or `Animal a = new Dog();` ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not using the interface of Dog here, you are using the interface of Animals. Which means, for example, if the class Dog has another method like "run" which the Animal class does not have, it won't be available for you to use here.

What I want to say is: there is no implicit nor explicit type casting at all

Answer (score 0):

This is Upcasting in polymorphism.  The line is below says that:

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

You use super class interface, but implementation is in subclass. Namely, You can use methods in Animal class on `a` reference, but the method's implementation is in Dog class.

Comment: so can we call it as implicit typecasting, b'coz which is done by compiler??  @mustafacil